# Writing to array inside an interator

Tags: rust

Is it possible to gain write access to array elements via an iterator?:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Struct {
    field: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut array: [Struct; 2] = [Default::default(), Default::default()];
    array[0].field = 2;
    array[1].field = 3;
    foo(&mut array);
    println!("[0]: {}", array[0].field);
    println!("[1]: {}", array[1].field);
}

fn foo(array: &mut [Struct]) {
    for (i, a) in array.iter().enumerate() {
        if a.field > 2 {
            println!("Setting [{}] to zero.", i);
            a.field = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this an idiomatic approach to solving the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to gain write access to array elements via an iterator?

Yes, but you have to use an iterator that returns mutable references. In this case, use [iter_mut](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter_mut), not [`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter).

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with `a = Default::default();` instead of `a.field = 0`?

Comment: @andreyg yes. `*a = Default::default();`